# When am I supposed to use UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleSingleLineEtched?

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I see a description of what `UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleSingleLineEtched` looks like in Apple's Class Reference, and can see it by running the application. But I can't find any mention of when it's **appropriate** to use `UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleSingleLineEtched` instead of `UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleSingleLine`.

In other words, what does this etched line *mean* to the user? Can anyone explain?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "why" part is because normal table cells have a white background and an etched look would not be appropriate, while the section heading cell has a gray background and adding a bit of highlight makes it pop out. At least, that's my interpretation.

Answer (score 4):

This is the description from Apple:

UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleSingleLine

```
The separator cell has a single line running across its width. This is the default value

Available in iPhone OS 2.0 and later.

Declared in UITableViewCell.h.
```

UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleSingleLineEtched

```
The separator cell has double lines running across its width, giving it an etched look. This style is currently only supported for grouped-style table views.

Available in iPhone OS 3.2 and later.

Declared in UITableViewCell.h.
```

So in my opinion, the SingleLineEtched will look more clear separation, make 2 groups differentiate to each other, because it contains double lines

Comment: I found that. :) It's a very good explanation of what, but not why. Apple usually doesn't do two visual styles without them each meaning something. But maybe this is an exception.

Answer (score 0):

The etched appearance is for iPad tableViews, which don't have the pinstripe background you see on the iPhone. That, at least, appears to be the convention.